# WCF service response design based on grouping c#

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns

I need help with design of my WCF service. I have a method which returns `Products` from database. On user interface I have following options to group products:

1. No/Default Grouping: returns list of all `Products`.
2. Manufacturer Grouping: returns list of all `Products` according to a specific manufacture.
3. Taxable Grouping: returns list of all `Products`which are taxable.

**Below is my entire response structure:**

```
<ResponseStruct>
  <!-- Grouping is done on product-->
    <ProductList>
        <Product>
            <Name></Name>
            <Taxability>
                <Value></Value>
            </Taxability>
            <ManufacturerList>
                <Manufacturer>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <City></City>
                </Manufacturer>
                <Manufacturer>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <City></City>
                </Manufacturer>
            </ManufacturerList>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name></Name>
            <Taxability>
                <Value></Value>
            </Taxability>
            <ManufacturerList>
                <Manufacturer>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <City></City>
                </Manufacturer>
                <Manufacturer>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <City></City>
                </Manufacturer>
            </ManufacturerList>
        </Product>
    </ProductList>

  <!-- Grouping is done on taxability of product-->
    <TaxabilityList>
        <Taxability>
            <Value></Value>
            <ProductList>
                <Product>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <ManufacturerList>
                        <Manufacturer>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <City></City>
                        </Manufacturer>
                        <Manufacturer>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <City></City>
                        </Manufacturer>
                    </ManufacturerList>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <ManufacturerList>
                        <Manufacturer>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <City></City>
                        </Manufacturer>
                        <Manufacturer>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <City></City>
                        </Manufacturer>
                    </ManufacturerList>
                </Product>
            </ProductList>
        </Taxability>
        <Taxability>
            <Value></Value>
            <ProductList>
                <Product>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <ManufacturerList>
                        <Manufacturer>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <City></City>
                        </Manufacturer>
                        <Manufacturer>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <City></City>
                        </Manufacturer>
                    </ManufacturerList>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <ManufacturerList>
                        <Manufacturer>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <City></City>
                        </Manufacturer>
                        <Manufacturer>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <City></City>
                        </Manufacturer>
                    </ManufacturerList>
                </Product>
            </ProductList>
        </Taxability>
    </TaxabilityList>

  <!-- Grouping is done on manufacterur-->
    <ManufacturerList>
        <Manufacturer>
            <Name></Name>
            <City></City>
            <ProductList>
                <Product>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Taxability>
                        <Value></Value>
                    </Taxability>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Taxability>
                        <Value></Value>
                    </Taxability>
                </Product>
            </ProductList>
        </Manufacturer>
        <Manufacturer>
            <Name></Name>
            <City></City>
            <ProductList>
                <Product>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Taxability>
                        <Value></Value>
                    </Taxability>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Taxability>
                        <Value></Value>
                    </Taxability>
                </Product>
            </ProductList>
        </Manufacturer>
    </ManufacturerList>
</ResponseStruct>
```

Right now I solved this problem in following way:
First I have identified the individual Model classes for my response.

```
1.  Product
-   Name
-   Taxability
-   IList<Manufacturer>
2.  Taxability
-   Value
-   IList<Product>
3.  Manufacturer
-   Name
-   City
-   IList<Product>
```

For use case 1(default grouping) I leave both ManufacturerList and TaxabilityList tag closed in response and fill the ProductList object only from database. For use case 2(Grouping based on manufacturer) I leave product ProductList and TaxabilityList closed in response and only fill ManufacturerList object.

*Sample response for use case 3:*

```
<ResponseStruct>
  <ProductList/>
  <ManufacturerList/>
  <TaxabilityList>...</TaxabilityList>
</ResponseStruct>
```

**Need help:**

Above is the sample I have created which demonstrate my problem. In reality there are 5 Grouping option and User input request can have 2 level grouping(he can send it in array of grouping object in request) and this results in 20 possible response format.

> There is an issue with my implementation. I have three layers in my
>   service and when I receive input, I set a flag after looking at
>   grouping attribute in input request under input validation layer which
>   is later used by business layer where I format response based grouping
>   attribute from input, this was getting messy because of lot ‘if’
>   statement, so I created different response formatter classes which
>   implements an interface but my concern is that I have created too many
>   classes because I have to build multiple response formats(20).

Is there any design pattern of subject matter or any suggestion which I can read to solve my problem?

I might be approaching my problem in completely wrong way, so will appreciate any kind of solution.

Comment: I edited your question for clarifying what you need. As I understand about your question, all of responses include list of product that are grouped by 3 options. If I am wrong please notice right information. I have come up with an idea for your question but I am a little bit confused about what exactly you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the complexities of this problem lies in having different properties per group representation. As an example, when you group by *Manufacturer*, you'd have the name / address of the *grouper* but when you group by *Taxability* you'd have the values. I thought a bit about it, the solution that I'll propose will very likely to lead to slight UI changes but it might give you some class(es) to handle this type of data.

To begin with, from now on everything is a `GroupedCollection`. It doesn't matter if the user hasn't selected anything, it's still *grouped by* nothing. Our `GroupedCollection` class should be a collection of collections.

The inner collection is going to have the details - the outer collection is going to be just the collection.

So to put it into the code - it would look like this.

```
// This class is responsible from carrying information + items belonging to a single group.
public class SingleGroupCollection<N> : Collection<N>
    {
        //
        // The property bag is where you carry the per-group data.
        // Like your grouped-by Manufacturer <"name", "G. Manufacturer">
        // You should expose methods so you could retrieve all of its 
        // keys-values and display the group-specific data in your UI.

        Dictionary<string, string> PropertyBag;
        public SingleGroupCollection()
        {
             // Classic .Add() / .Remove() methods should work since 
             //   we inherit from a Collection.
        }
    }
```

Now that we have a `SingleGroupCollection<Product>` class - we need something to hold all of the groups. We can create the class below:

```
/*
    This class will hold all of the data that you're tranferring across.
    Depending on the grouping type - which I've imagined to be an enum, 
    you can set to be only 1 group / vs multiple groups,
    fill the class as you see fit with the information that you've retrieved from the DB.
 */
public class GroupedCollection<N> : Collection<SingleGroupCollection<N>>
    {
        public GroupedCollection()
        {
            // default
        }

        public GroupedCollection(GroupingType[] type)
        {
            // set types
            // set collection
        }
    }
```

This way you can extend / reuse the `GroupedCollection` class while supporting multiple GroupingTypes and still have a single type of response.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which UI framework you're using, you could implement the grouping client-side.  Then the service doesn't need to be concerned with all the different grouping use-cases and can return the data as-is, ungrouped.

If you must do grouping server-side I would build different methods for each scenario, but with common contracts.  Some pseduo-code:

```
interface MyService
{
    IList<Product> GetProducts();
    IList<Group<Product>> GetProductsGroupedByTaxability();
    IList<Group<Product>> GetProductsGroupedByManufacturer();
}

class Group<T>
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

If I understand the question correctly, your real problem though is that the grouping must be dynamic and multi-level (e.g.: group by manufacturer, or group by manufacturer and then by taxability)  If you can reasonably constrain clients to two levels of grouping, then the following contract might work for you.

```
interface MyService
{
    IList<Product> GetProducts();
    IList<Group<Product>> GetGroupedProducts(Field level1);
    IList<Group<IList<Group<Product>>> GetGroupedProducts(Field level1, Field level2);
}

enum Field { Manufacturer, Taxability }
```

The highly nested generics get hard to read pretty quickly, but would yield a response something like this for single-level.

```
<Groups>
    <Group>
        <Name>Massey Fergusson</Name>
        <Items>
            <Product>...</Product>
            <Product>...</Product>
            <Product>...</Product>
        </Items>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Name>John Deere</Name>
        <Items>
            <Product>...</Product>
            <Product>...</Product>
            <Product>...</Product>
        </Items>
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

And for two-level:

```
<Groups>
    <Group>
        <Name>Massey Fergusson</Name>
        <Items>
            <Group>
                <Name>20%</Name>
                <Items>
                    <Product>...</Product>
                    <Product>...</Product>
                </Items>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <Name>0%</Name>
                <Items>
                    <Product>...</Product>
                    <Product>...</Product>
                </Items>
            </Group>
        </Items>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Name>John Deere</Name>
        <Items>
            ...
        </Items>
    </Group>
</Groups>
```